# Prolog - rule to determine date and status of object.

Tags: prolog, compare, conditional-statements, rule

Firstly, here is my code so far:

```
number_book(111, brave_new_world).
number_book(222, lord_of_the_flies).
number_book(333, fight_club).
number_book(444, wind_in_the_willows).
number_book(555, the_hobbit).
author_book(huxley_aldus, brave_new_world).
author_book(golding_william, lord_of_the_flies).
author_book(palahniuk_chuck, fight_club).
author_book(grahame_kenneth, wind_in_the_willows).
author_book(tolkien_jrr, the_hobbit).
author_fore_sur(huxley_aldus, aldus, huxley).
author_fore_sur(golding_william, william, golding).
author_fore_sur(palahniuk_chuck, chuck, palahniuk).
author_fore_sur(grahame_kenneth, kenneth, grahame).
author_fore_sur(tolkien_jrr, jrr, tolkien).

id_sur_fore(1202, smith, john).
id_sur_fore(1332, thompson, kevin).
id_sur_fore(4556, anderson, edward).
house_post_id(5, dh1_3pr, 1202).
house_post_id(123, ne3_4ty, 1332).
house_post_id(45, dh3_6kl, 4556).

borrowed_id(333, 1202).
borrowed_id(222, 1332).
borrowed_id(555, 4556).

book_out(333,11_06_2014).
book_out(222,15_06_2014).
book_out(555,17_06_2014).
book_in(333, 19_06_2014).
book_in(222, 26_07_2014).
book_in(555, 01_07_2014).

due_date(D) :- book_in(N, D1), D @< D1.
```

What I want to be able to do is to determine which books are on loan and to whom, and whether or not the book is overdue. Due to a lack of experience with Prolog, I haven't the foggiest where to begin, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First, you should use a different representation for the date. Your intention to compare atoms that represent dates (in the format 'day_month_year') alphabetically will get you wrong results (e.g. `?- '01_01_2014' @< '31_01_1900'.` is `true`). Use `date(Year,Month,Day)` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use `date(Year, Month, Day)` to represent dates. Then you can use `@</2` to compare them. To find out which books where on loan on a specific day, you can use a rule like this:

```
on_loan(D, Title):-
    book_out(Id, D1), D1 @=< D,
    book_in(Id, D2), D @< D2,
    number_book(Id, Title).
```

Now, to get all books on loan in a specific day:

```
all_on_loan(D, All) :- findall(Title, on_loan(D, Title), All).
```

And if you are interested in all books on loan today:

```
all_on_loan_today(All) :- date(D), all_on_loan(D, All).
```

Comment: Would there be a way to calculate the number of days between the book_due and book_in functors? so far I have (to no avail): 
    overdue(N1,N) :-
        book_in(N1, D1),
 book_due(N1, D2),
 N = D1 - D2.  '

Comment: I think you have to do the arithmetic on your own.

Comment: And you should post a separate question on SO for that.

Comment: Noted, thanks for the advice was a big help, its running smoothly now.